Create tree folded structure from comments in code
I look for plugin for Kate or Geany that can generate tree structure from code comments, the example is Anchors in VS code https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ExodiusStudios.comment-anchors
Do you know anything similar?
Thank you in advance!
